# nginx redirection

Tags: regex, nginx, redirect

I have a nginx server (called mynginxserver) and need to redirect some urls :

I want to have all url with the string odb:

```
http://www.mynginxserver.com/XXXXXXodbXXXXX
```

redirected to

```
http://www.myodbserver.com/XXXXXXodbXXXXX
```

if the string odb is in the url and redirect to

```
http://www.mynotodbserver.com/XXXXXXXXXXX
```

if the string odb is not present.

- XXXXXXodbXXXXX and XXXXXXXXXXX must be keep.
- The string "odb" can ben anywhere in the last parameter (odbXXXXX, XodbXXXX, XXXXodb, etc.)

I think i need to use the location and rewrite directive but don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Please share me Some Code , i will try to improve

This regex will help to identify the link that not having 'odb' string..

```
http:\/\/www.\w+.com\/[^odb]*$
```

Search using that regex , if condition fails means ,you simply redirect to

```
http://www.myodbserver.com/XXXXXXodbXXXXX
```

Comment: Sorry, i have no code a this time. I try some redirect using the rewrite directive of nginx but nothing works.

Comment: @Davy, At least tell me in which language you want? Is that okay for you in python??

Comment: It's for nginx who seems to use syntax similar to perl language.